# Design pattern for database access library and abstract class as a return type

Tags: c++

I've got an interface for accessing different kind of databases through it so - MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite... I've got a method declared in my abstract class:

```
virtual Result* ExecuteQuery(const char* query) = 0;
```

In each of implementations I dynamically create an object for the result of specified database but the problem is I've got to call delete each time I call ExecuteQuery.

```
Database* database=new MySQLDatabase(.........);
if(database.Connect(....)){
   Result* result = database.ExecuteQuery(...);
   //using result here ...

   delete result; // I must call delete 
}
```

What I want is to use result without carrying about freeing the memory.

Comment: Having to explicitly `delete` that object (and objects in general) isn't necessarily bad. There are a few mechanisms to avoid that (see answers), but since C++ does not have a garbage collector (as Java or Python do, for instance), it's a pretty normal thing to do. In C it would be exactly the same, you would have to call `free()`. See some `glib` usage patterns, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` in your ExecuteQuery method so instead of returning a naked (raw) Result pointer, you'll return a smart pointer wrapping the Result pointer - it will be destructed (automatically via delete) when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `unique_ptr`, something like:

```
unigue_ptr<Result> result(database.ExecuteQuery(...));
```